# properties file not found after migrating Android project from eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle, resources

My Android project contains some property files in the package structure. To read this property I use `MyClass.getResourceAsStream("someProperties.xml")`. MyClass has no access to a Context.
After migrating to Android Studio the `someProperties.xml` is not moved into the resulting package structure. Therefore my code can't find the file.
What can I do to read my file again? How can I modify the gradle build to have the file copied to my package structure again or is the a possibility to read resources without a context and put the file into `assets`?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have not specified within gradle where those resources are located.
Defaults are different in Eclipse ADT and Android Studio.

Here are defaults for Eclipse (when java sources already in `src/main/java`)

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
}
```

see [MAKE ANDROID ECLIPSE PROJECT READY FOR ANDROID STUDIO, YET KEEPING IT ACCESSIBLE FOR ECLIPSE USE TOO](http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/android/Make-Android-Eclipse-project-ready-for-Android-Studio)